# Formatting date with moment js

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I am using moment js in react,
how can I format date like this **[2022m12d23]** and **[2022m12]** ?

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between then result and expected output

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but still...understand why you don't need momentjs https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add square bracket between expected string for example `[m]` or `[d]`

The format as below

`YYYY[m]MM[d]DD` or `YYYY[m]MM`

Reference: https://momentjs.com/